# _corrupt_record error when reading a JSON file into Spark

Tags: python, json, dataframe, pyspark

I've got this JSON file

```
{
    "a": 1, 
    "b": 2
}
```

which has been obtained with Python json.dump method.
Now, I want to read this file into a DataFrame in Spark, using pyspark. Following documentation, I'm doing this

> sc = SparkContext()
>
> sqlc = SQLContext(sc)
>
> df = sqlc.read.json('my_file.json')
>
> print df.show()

The print statement spits out this though:

```
+---------------+
|_corrupt_record|
+---------------+
|              {|
|       "a": 1, |
|         "b": 2|
|              }|
+---------------+
```

Anyone knows what's going on and why it is not interpreting the file correctly?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You need to have one json object per row in your input file, see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.json.html

If your json file looks like this it will give you the expected dataframe:

```
{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }
{ "a": 3, "b": 4 }

....
df.show()
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  3|  4|
+---+---+
```

Comment: How can I fix it if my JSON file is huge (a couple of 100K rows) and it has a lot of new lines in between the records (columns or features)? thanks.

Comment: Maybe use `jq` to reformat(compact) the file? @M.Rez

Comment: @ttimasdf Namely, using `jq -c` option.

Answer (score 84):

If you want to leave your JSON file as it is (without stripping new lines characters `\n`), include `multiLine=True` keyword argument

```
sc = SparkContext() 
sqlc = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlc.read.json('my_file.json', multiLine=True)

print df.show()
```

Answer (score 26):

In Spark 2.2+ you can read json file of multiline using following command.

```
val dataframe = spark.read.option("multiline",true).json( " filePath ")
```

if there is json object per line then,

```
val dataframe = spark.read.json(filepath)
```

Comment: This is scala, not python.

Comment: Still works in Python however `spark.read.option("multiline",True).json('filePath')`

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @Bernhard's great answer

```
# original file was written with pretty-print inside a list
with open("pretty-printed.json") as jsonfile:
    js = json.load(jsonfile)      

# write a new file with one object per line
with open("flattened.json", 'a') as outfile:
    for d in js:
        json.dump(d, outfile)
        outfile.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

I want to share my experience in which I have a JSON column String  but with Python notation, which means I have `None` instead of `null`, `False` instead of `false` and `True` instead of `true`.

When parsing this column, spark returns me a column named `_corrupt_record`. So what I had to do before parsing the JSON String is replacing the Python notation with the standard JSON notation:

```
df.withColumn("json_notation",
    F.regexp_replace(F.regexp_replace(F.regexp_replace("_corrupt_record", "None", "null"), "False", "false") ,"True", "true")
```

After this transformation I was then able to use for example the function `F.from_json()` on the `json_notation` column and here Pyspark was able to correctly parse the JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

One another reason of this happening could be file encoding. If the file you are reading is say for example in latin encoding you will get this issue. Try using .option("encoding", "cp1252") while reading file. This resolved the issue for me