# How to parse json column in dataframe in scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame which is json column with json string. example below. There are 3 columns - a,b,c. Column c is stringType

```
| a         | b    |           c                       |
--------------------------------------------------------
|77         |ABC   |    {"12549":38,"333513":39}       |
|78         |ABC   |    {"12540":38,"333513":39}       |
```

I want to make them into columns of the data frame(pivot). the example below -

```
| a         | b    | 12549  | 333513 | 12540
---------------------------------------------
|77         |ABC   |38      |39      | null
|77         |ABC   | null   |39      | 38
```

Comment: Does the json always have the same format?

Comment: I think you need more cleaner explanation.

Comment: @Oli json columns are not fixed. Json is always same format

Comment: So what would be the logic in that case? Could you provide an example that fully reflects what you are trying to do? (and possibly a more extensive explanation)

Comment: updated question.

Comment: Oh right, nice. And it is possible to have nested elements s.a. `{"a":{"x" : 4, "y" : 7}}`?

Comment: max distinct fields in JSON will not more than 5.

Comment: No,  it will always {"x" : 4, "y" : 7}.  where x and y are viable

Comment: @JiriS It is different. It is a pivoting problem

Comment: There is no pivot here. This is a regular projection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may not be the most efficient, as it has to read all of the `json` records an extra time to infer the schema. If you can statically define the schema, it should do better.

```
val data = spark.createDataset(Seq(
  (77, "ABC", "{\"12549\":38,\"333513\":39}"),
  (78, "ABC", "{\"12540\":38,\"333513\":39}")
)).toDF("a", "b", "c")

val schema = spark.read.json(data.select("c").as[String]).schema

data.select($"a", $"b", from_json($"c", schema).as("s")).select("a", "b", "s.*").show(false)
```

Result:

```
+---+---+-----+-----+------+
|a  |b  |12540|12549|333513|
+---+---+-----+-----+------+
|77 |ABC|null |38   |39    |
|78 |ABC|38   |null |39    |
+---+---+-----+-----+------+
```

Comment: great. But I am getting _corrupt_record column also

Comment: Some of your json data is either corrupt or contains newlines. You can try with a multiline option `val schema = spark.read.option("multiline", true).json(data.select("c").as[String]).schema` or you'll have to filter or correct the corrupt data: [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35409539/corrupt-record-error-when-reading-a-json-file-into-spark)

Comment: How to make the header be something like "a, b, json_12540, json_12549, json_333513"?

Comment: To do this dynamically, I think you'd have to iterate `df.columns` and selectively rename them individually with `.withColumnRenamed()`. I will reiterate, however, that a static schema would be much more performant in this case.