# How to convert complex JSON to dataframe by using PySpark?

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I require a python code to convert the JSON to dataframe.

My JSON format is

```
{"feed":{"catalog":{"schema":["somekey":"somevalue"], "add":{"items":[{["somekey":"somevalue"]}]}}....
```

I want the JSON into multiple dataframe which are present inside the items.

**For example:**

**Input JSON**

```
{"feed":{"catalog":{"schema":["somekey":"somevalue"], "add":{"items":[{[{"sku":"10002","status":"Enabled"},{"sku":"10003","status":"Enabled"}]}]}}
```

**Expected Dataframe**

```
sku      status

100002   Enabled

1000023  Enabled
```

Thanks in advance, please help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explode `items` array to get `sku,status` columns.

```
#sample valid json
jsn='{"feed":{"catalog":{"schema":["somekey","somevalue"], "add":{"items":[{"sku":"10002","status":"Enabled"},{"sku":"10003","status":"Enabled"}]}}}}'

#read the json using spark.read.json
df=spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([jsn]))

#print schema
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- feed: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |-- catalog: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- add: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |    |    |-- items: array (nullable = true)
# |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
# |    |    |    |    |    |-- sku: string (nullable = true)
# |    |    |    |    |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- schema: array (nullable = true)
# |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

df.withColumn("items",explode(col("feed.catalog.add.items"))).\
select("items.*").\
show()
#+-----+-------+
#|  sku| status|
#+-----+-------+
#|10002|Enabled|
#|10003|Enabled|
#+-----+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you Thank you So Much for your answer. I am facing one more problem (i.e.) I have JSON in file, if I print the schema It shows root
 |-- _corrupt_record: string (nullable = true)............ So, I am unable to use above solution........... What should I do. Can you help me?

Comment: @tsuresh97, make sure you are having a valid `json` formatted file! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35409539/corrupt-record-error-when-reading-a-json-file-into-spark

Comment: Thanks for your solution, got it.