# Pyspark dataframe corrupted record when reading from python dictionary(json) got from requests, encoding problem

Tags: python, apache-spark, encoding, pyspark, python-requests

I am making a REST api call with Requests library.

`response = requests.get("https://urltomaketheapicall", headers={'authorization': 'bearer {0}'.format("7777777777777777777777777777")}, timeout=5)`

When I do `response.json()`

I get a key with these values

`{'devices': '....iPhone\xa05S, iPhone\xa06, iPhone\xa06\xa0Plus, iPhone\xa06S'}`

When I do `print(response.encoding)` I get `None`

When I do `print(type(data[devices]))` I get `<class 'str'>`

If i do `print(data[devices])` I get `'....iPhone 5S, iPhone 6, iPhone 6 Plus, iPhone 6S'` without the special characters.

Now if do

```
new_dict={}
new_val = data[devices]
new_dict["devices"] = new_val
print(new_dict["devices"])
```

I will get the special characters in the new dictionary as well.

Any ideas?

I want to get rid of the special characters since I need to read these json and put it in a pyspark dataframe and with those characters i get a [_corrupted_record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35409539/corrupt-record-error-when-reading-a-json-file-into-spark)

```
rd= spark.sparkContext.parallelize([data])
df = spark.read.json(rd)
```

I want to avoid solutions like `.replace("\\xa0"," ")`

Answer (score 0):

`A0` is a no-break space. It's simply part of the string. It simply prints like that because you're dumping the repr of an entire dict. It'll simply print as proper no-break space if you print the individual string:

```
>>> print({'a': '\xa0'})
{'a': '\xa0'}
>>> print('\xa0')
 
>>>
```

Comment: check my edit, with the special characters i can not put it in a pyspark dataframe

Comment: Concentrate another question on that specifically then. I don't know pyspark and whether you're simply doing it wrong, or whether it simply can't handle no-break spaces.