# Writing JSON content to HDFS location using Python

Tags: python, json, hdfs, python-hdfs

I am trying to write JSON content to HDFS  location using Python,but for every key and value in my JSON content, I am seeing prefix of u and ''.

Original JSON content
{
"id": 2344556,
"resource_type": "user",
"ext_uid": null,
"email": "Richard.John@abc.com",
"name": "Rich John",
"role": "manager",
"role_id": 5944
}

```
import os 
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth 
users_url = "https://api.test.com/api/k1/users"
response = requests.get(users_url,auth = authParams) 
users_json = response.json()
os.system(' echo "%s" | hadoop fs -put - hdfs://hadoopnode/user/uui123/API_JSON/user.json' %(users_json))
```

Output it's writing in hdfs location

{
u'id': u'2344556',
u'resource_type': u'user',
u'ext_uid': u'null',
u'email': u'Richard.John@abc.com',
u'name': u'Rich John',
u'role': u'manager',
u'role_id': u'5944'
}
How I can get my original content hdfs file without prefix u and ''

Comment: You need to `json.dumps` the dictionary into a string , but you really shouldn't be using hdfs for such a small file

Comment: Also, if you were to use Spark, then you shouldn't be using shell commands to write to hdfs

Comment: @OneCricketeer ,it is a big file and want to write this to hdfs before i process it with dataframe.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I tried this json.dumps  and it's writing empty file

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you changed, but anything less than 128MB is not big for HDFS, and any http response that large will likely timeout with Python requests module defaults

Comment: @OneCricketeer, here is the actual problem, when read  JSON response directly in to spark I'm getting a single _corrept_record column,but when I write JSON response to a file and if i read that file with spark is  working fine.                                                                                https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35409539/corrupt-record-error-when-reading-a-json-file-into-spark

Comment: If that's the actual problem, then edit your question to show that. The issue would be the url is returning you more than a single object or it has indentation, and Spark expects jsonlines (one json object per line) format, not a single object spread over multiple lines like a http response would return