# How to convert None values in Json to null using Pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark

Currently I am parsing my Json feeds with:

```
rdd = self.spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(json_feed)])
df = self.spark.read.json(rdd)
```

That works fine as long as values are all there, but if I have a Json (as Python dict) like:

```
json_feed = { 'name': 'John', 'surname': 'Smith', 'age': None }
```

I would like to get the generated DataFrame with a value `null` on the `age` column, but what I am getting at the moment is `_corrupt_record`. Is there a way to parse `None` values to `null` with Pyspark?

Comment: I don't think the None value is an issue here, it seems more like the source JSON file is not in the format the reader expects it to be. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35409539/corrupt-record-error-when-reading-a-json-file-into-spark

Answer (score 0):

Importing JSON with missing values is very restrictive with Spark. An easy workaround is to read the file as text and parse with required schema.

Assume a JSON with missing "age" field:

```
!cat /content/sample_data/test.json

{ "name": "John", "surname": "Smith" }
```

First, read the file as text and then create dataframe from it with required schema:

```py
rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile("/content/sample_data/test.json").map(eval)

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=rdd, schema="name string, surname string, age int")

df.show(truncate=False)
+----+-------+----+
|name|surname|age |
+----+-------+----+
|John|Smith  |null|
+----+-------+----+

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- surname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: integer (nullable = true)
```